# How to manage Expiration of Redisson nested Objects

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am using Redisson library to manage data in redis and have following POJO's (leaving get/set/constructor here).

```
@REntity  
Class A {
  @RId
  String id;
  ....
  List<B> listOfB;
}

@REntity
class B {
 @RId
 String id
 .....
}
```

Both A and B instances are created using RLiveObjectService and are set to expire using asRExpirable.
First issue is instances of Class B were not expiring - to address that i am marking B instances asExpirable explicitly.
But i am still left with 'listOfB' hashes in redis from Class A and they never get removed/expired. 
How to handle this so these are also expired? 
I assume nested LiveObjects expiration still not supported (redisson 3.11.1). Looking for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Here is how addressing it (Getting List from A Instance, assigning to RList)-

> RList<> = (RList<>) a.getListOfB()

Mark RList expirable in addition to A and B Instances.